# How do I make a link that embed the video player below the link

Tags: php

So I have a video sharing website, written in PHP. Now when a share a link, it will just show the link. But I want it to have a embed video part below the link. Here's the screenshot of what I mean.
[image: Example Image]

Is there any way to implement it?
Thank you :)

Comment: echo "<a href='" . $_POST['shared_link'] . "'>Link</a>";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to share it as like sharing a youtube video link with preview thumbnails then may be this helps you.
I think you need to use the og tag which helps you to preview a link while sending on social media as thumbnails. if you mean that you use it.

create og tag and placed it in meta tag in head section like this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://domain_name.com/ftp_path/image_name.png"/>
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="680" />
```

this og tag helps you to view your link image while sharing. and you also have to mention title and description if you want.
may be you try it.